# Vitest coverage on azure devops

Tags: azure, vue.js, devops, pipeline, vitest

I'm trying to run an azure devops pipeline that contains a vitest run with coverage. The issue is that the azure coverage collector plugin accepts only jacoco/cobertura formats.
I've seen that for jest is it possible to run with a cobertura reporter. Is there anyway of doing this for vitest?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Vitest [supports c8 and istanbul](https://vitest.dev/guide/coverage.html#coverage-providers) for coverage, they both support Cobertura format.

Wherever you define your test settings `vite.config.ts` or `vitest.config.ts` set the coverage reporter to generate the cobertura format.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    coverage: {
      reporter: ['cobertura', 'text'],
    },
  },
})
```

It will output by default at `/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml`.  You can then feed this into the `PublishCodeCoverageResults` task.

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions but I didn't find a solution. I opened a thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76677625/show-vitest-coverage-on-azure-devops-ui