# Vitest unit test coverage in React App not show up

Tags: reactjs, vitest

I've a React App with a set of unit tests in it. The test framework are Vitest with React test library. Here are the details of the library App is using:

```
"react": "^17.0.0",
"react-dom": "^17.0.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
"@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
"@vitest/coverage-c8": "^0.28.5",
"global-jsdom": "^8.7.0",
"jsdom": "^21.1.0",
"typescript": "^4.9.5",
"vite": "^4.1.0",
"vitest": "^0.28.5",
"vitest-canvas-mock": "^0.2.2"
```

Here are the script configuration in package.json:

```
"test": "vitest run",
"coverage": "vitest run --coverage",
```

In test section of vite.config.ts, here is the coverage configuraiton:

```
coverage: {
  reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html', 'lcov'],
},
```

When performing npm run coverage, the unit tests have been run correctly and the test result can be found. Howerver, the output of the coverage report is an empty as shown below:

[Here is the test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFpIV.png)

Test Files  15 passed (15)
Tests  55 passed (55)
Start at  15:28:04
Duration  34.14s (transform 1.99s, setup 3.56s, collect 14.22s, tests 8.22s)

% Coverage report from c8

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------

A list of files have been tested and coverage info should be returned.
Any idea why an empty coverage report was returned even the unit tests have been run correclty?

Comment: try running: ` vitest run --coverage.enabled --coverage.all --coverage.src='./src' --coverage.reporter='text-summary' --coverage.reporter='lcov'`
it could be, that you have to specify "all" & "src" options

Comment: the simple solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75077979/621951)