# Show Vitest coverage on Azure DevOps UI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, jestjs, azure-pipelines, vitest

I would render my vitest coverage in Azure DevOps UI, I've tried to follow tutorials but it doesn't work:

[image]

I tried to setup PublishCodeCoverageResults to publish the cobertura xml file as in below:

```
      - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
        displayName: 'Publish code coverage results'
        inputs:
          codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
          summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*coverage.xml'
          reportDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage'
```

I run Vitest with this command `vitest --coverage --no-threads` and this is my vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths()],
  test: {
    coverage: {
      reporter: ['cobertura', 'text'],
    },
    include: ['packages/core/test/*'],
  },
});
```

This is the output of PublishCodeCoverageResults
[image]

If I run `cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml`

It show me the cobertura file (this is a part of the entire file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE coverage SYSTEM "http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/xml/coverage-04.dtd">
<coverage lines-valid="1502" lines-covered="1240" line-rate="0.8255" branches-valid="29" branches-covered="26" branch-rate="0.8965000000000001" timestamp="1689237532968" complexity="0" version="0.1">
  <sources>
    <source>/home/vsts/work/1/s</source>
  </sources>
  <packages>
    <package name="core.src" line-rate="0.8223999999999999" branch-rate="0.8928">
      <classes>
        <class name="dynamo.ts" filename="packages/core/src/dynamo.ts" line-rate="1" branch-rate="1">
          <methods>
          </methods>
          <lines>
            <line number="1" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="2" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="3" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="4" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="5" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="6" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="7" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="8" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="9" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="10" hits="1" branch="false"/>
          </lines>
        </class>
        <class name="order.ts" filename="packages/core/src/order.ts" line-rate="0.8349" branch-rate="0.8887999999999999">
          <methods>
            <method name="defau
```

In the artifacts of pipeline I can see this new folder:
[image]

Comment: The code coverage tab doesn't show until the pipeline is complete.  If you cancel or finish that dev step does it show up?

See this [Azure DevOps issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/code-coverage-does-not-show-up-until-multistage-pi/786733).

Comment: Thank you Steven! Yes I confirm, now I can see Coverage tab when pipeline is complete but I still don't see any information on main tab (the first screenshot on my topic).

Comment: what rules should I enable in BuildCheckQuality task to show coverage on single stage?